# Plot surface defined by inequality

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I have an inequality which looks like

```
5 < x < 25 && 5 < y < 25 && z == 3
```

And I would like to plot this surface. However, `RegionPlot3D` returns a blank when `z==3`.

```
RegionPlot3D[ 5 < x < 25 && 5 < y < 25 && z == 3, {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 30}, {z, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

I have to manually change the `z` equality to something like

```
  RegionPlot3D[ 5 < x < 25 && 5 < y < 25 && 2.8 < z < 3, {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 30}, {z, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Is there a better way to plot this surface?

Comment: Is this a general question? Because if not then you can just use `Polygon` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For arbitrary implicite regions it is easy to use:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[5 < x < 25 && 5 < y < 25 && z == 3, {x, y, z}];
Region[R, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 30}, {0, 5}}, Boxed -> True,Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple workaround.

Choose PlotPoints so that there are points to be plotted at exactly z==3.
For example with {z,1,5} choose 3 as the lowest odd number of PlotPoints in z direction.
But in order not to get round edges, choose high numbers for x and y direction, best multiples of the x-range and y-range.

```
RegionPlot3D[
    5 < x < 25 && 5 < y < 25 && z == 3, {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 30}, {z, 1, 
    5}, PlotPoints -> {60, 60, 3}]
```

[image]